# Windows 7 deployment: send image to a different site

Tags: windows

I am currently using MDT for windows 7 deployment for the local office. (no WDS involved since we don't have an Active Directory domain controller). Works great.

Now there is a small team based in a remote location. Their PCs are normally in a workgroup, and they are connected to our network via VPN.

I don't have access to LAN desk or SCCM at all. So what's the good options to help deploying a  Windows 7 image (laptops included) on their machines?

The ideal option will be creating an image, sending the image to them via secure file transfer to them, together with an easy-2-follow instruction, so that they can get things going themselves. -- at least that's what I envisaged.

Any suggestions experts?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to capture a install.wim file and deploy it with windows setup on a USB stick.  See [msdn for an example](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722053%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  The example listed has the image on a network share, but the wim can also be placed on the installation media.

That being said, I have never attempted such an endeavor, and don't know what issues you may encounter.